# Once they release a shiny is it always in the game?

Tags: pokemon-go

Outside of events like go fest, once they release a shiny version into the game will you always have a small chance of getting it if the pokemon is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/pokemon-go-shinies-list) article, yes:

> Once a Pokemon is made available as a shiny Pokemon, it is possible to receive a shiny variant in any way the Pokemon is obtainable. Evolved Pokemon cannot be caught shiny. They must be caught shiny in the basic stage, then evolved. The exception to this rule is Pikachu (and now Nidorina and Nidoqueen), who can be caught shiny.

Comment: Fun fact: When Generation 3 first came out, there was a bug that allowed trainers to find Shiny Altarias in the wild (my friend was one of them). They fixed the bug shortly after though

Comment: Regarding evolved Pokemon not being shiny, Alolan Exeggutor can be caught shiny in the wild. There was also previously a 3-hour event for Gengar in Level 4 raids where it could be caught shiny.

Comment: @MBorg Alolan Exeggutor (and Raichu) are special cases too, since their basic forms can't evolve into the alolan forms. As for Gengar, the OP was curious about shines outside events and 3 hour raid windows are technically an in-game event :)

Comment: This is true in theory, but there have been multiple times where there was a bug that made a previously shiny Pokemon impossible to catch as shiny for a while.

Answer (score 1):

It will always be in the game.  For a while the way they introduced new shiny Pokemon to the game would be at the time of their corresponding event.  You definitely have a chance to catch them even though it is a small one.  Your best bet is to click on as many pokemon on the map as you see whether you want to catch it or not so that you can see if it is a shiny.